# Azure Event Grid and Azure Event Hub

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid, azure-node-sdk

I am using Azure Services with node js. I am pushing and getting the messages from service bus. I want to know what is the role that of event grid , event hub. When i create them they want end point what is that. 
And how should i proceed

Comment: have a look at the following document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services

Answer (score 0):

Service Bus, Event Hub, and Event Grid are three different Azure services.

In a nutshell;

Service Bus provides queue and pub/sub messaging typologies to decouple business applications. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview

Event Hubs provides a commit log for event driven applications and supports high volume data ingestion architectures and pipelines. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-about

Event Grid provides solutions for event triggers for reactive apps. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview

Why do you need Event Hubs or Event Grid? Can you elaborate your design a little more?

Comment: i am building a messaging app. I am new to cloud. I want  to use Service Event Grid so that each time i send a message a event should get notified

Comment: please explain me the basic idea how should i do this

Comment: You might not need Event Grid for this. You can build an Azure Functions app with either Event Hubs trigger or Service bus trigger. This way your code gets executed every time there is a message in the hub or the queue. See the sample here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/durable-functions-producer-consumer/product-consume-messages-az-functions/